# Turn a group representation into a $\mathbb C[G]$-module, is the new multiplication an extension of the old one

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

In [these lecture notes](http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/group/gind2_3.html) by Daniel Bump the $\mathbb C[G]$-module of a group representation is contructed the following way. If $G$ is a finite (possible non-abelian) group, then the *group algebra* $\mathbb C[G]$ is the set of functions $f : G \to \mathbb C$ with the convolution product
$$
 (f_1 \ast f_2)(x) := \sum_{\begin{array}{c} y,z \in G \\ yz = x\end{array}} f_1(y)f_2(z).
$$
A (complex) representation of the group $G$ is a homomorphism $\pi : G \to GL(V)$ for some vector space $V$, denotes $(\pi, V)$. Given such a representation, we can define a multiplication $\mathbb C[G] \times V \rightarrow V$ by
$$
 f \cdot v := \sum_{g\in G} f(g) \pi(g) v.
$$
Now I am curious, reduces this multiplication to the multiplication $\mathbb C \times V \to V$  already given on the $\mathbb C$-vector space $V$?

To show this I embed $\mathbb C$ into $\mathbb C[G]$ by identifying $\mathbb C \cong \{ c \cdot \overline 1 : c \in \mathbb C \}$, i.e. each element with the constant function taking this element as its constant value. For $c$ denote this constant function by $\overline c : G \to \mathbb C$, and compute
\begin{align*} 
 \overline c \cdot v = 
   \sum_{g\in G} \overline c(g) \pi(g) v 
   = \sum_{g\in G} c \pi(g) v
   = c \sum_{g\in G} \pi(g) v.
\end{align*}
But I have no idea how to show that $\sum_{g\in G} \pi(g) v = v$ (if this holds at all)? This is my question, does it hold and this new multiplication reduces to the old one in the vector space, and if so, how to show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have the wrong copy of $\mathbb{C}$ inside $\mathbb{C}[G]$. Instead, you want to take $\mathbb{C}\cong\{c\cdot\delta_e\mid c\in\mathbb{C}\}$, where $\delta_e$ is the function
$$
\delta_e(g)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{if }g=e\\0&\mbox{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
In fact, there is an isomorphism of algebras 
$$\mathbb{C}[G]\cong\mathbb{C}G=\left\{\sum_g c_gg\mid c_g\in \mathbb{C}\right\}$$
Multiplication in the latter algebra is given by extending the multiplication in $G$ linearly. The isomorphism is given by $\delta_g\mapsto g$.

Comment: Yes of course, that works out smoothly! Answers my question, but let me also ask. The other embedding seems also very natural to me, so is there any way where it shows up, or is it also useful? I just started studying character theory, so I am still quite new and unexperienced.

Comment: @Stefan I added another comment which will hopefully explain what the embedding you used is.

Comment: Yes. I see, this would be $c \mapsto \sum_{g\in G} c g$, a totally different construction.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, but note that for $v\in V$, the elements $\sum_g cgv$, $c\in \mathbb{C}$ span an invariant subspace of $V$. This usually turns out to be 0 unless $V$ contains copies of the trivial module.

Comment: With $\sum_g cgv$ you mean $\sum_g c\pi(g)v$ (this confused me a little bit, as I said I am still new to this field). Okay, invariant means that for each $h \in G$ we must have $\pi(h) \left( \sum_g cgv \right)$ contained in this space (checking the basis elements is sufficient). As $\pi(h) \left( \sum_g cgv \right) = \sum_g c \pi(h)\pi(g) v = \sum_g c \pi(hg) v = \sum_g c \pi(g) v$ (the multiplication by $h$ just changes the order of summation, hence does not affects it) it is invariant. But why should this space be $0$?

Comment: @Stefan Well, this subspace would be a submodule of $V$. So, for any irreducible $V$ (other than the trivial module), there is no such submodule.

Comment: But in general $V$ is not irreducible? So you are just referring to this special case?

Comment: @Stefan You can decompose $V$ into a direct sum of irreducibles (This is Maschke's theorem). If the trivial module does not appear in the decomposition, then the element acts as 0. That's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: All right, get it :)